# Inhertiance of Layout Details on Template Standard Values

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a template A which has several sublayouts and web controls assigned to the StandardValues for the Layout Details. If I inherit from this template and create a new template B it inherits all the layout details from A and displays fine.

Now I had to change the Datasource for one of the web controls on template A. I selected the StandardValues went to Presentation>Details and changed the DataSource to point to the Item I want the control to use. The problem is even though I have done it on the StandardValues the change does not propagate to B. The value of DataSource on template A initially was empty and I changed it to /sitecore/content/Global/Item but the DataSource on the webcontrol in template B is still empty (shouldn't it display the inherited value?).

What are my options to have changes on base templates propagate to templates that are based on them?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you running? 
I tried your scenario on Sitecore 6.2.0.100104 and it works as expected.

Comment: Hi Sean,

Im running 6.1.0 - 090821

Comment: Is Template B still using the standard value on the '__Renderings' field?  (You might have to enable the viewing of standard fields in the View tab of the content editor, if you can't see it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi talked to Sitecore support the other day and apparently what I experience is expected behaviour. Here is a link on how to implement inheritance for Layout Details: [Layout Detail Inheritance](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/composite-presentation-inheritance/)  .

It seemed like a bit of an overkill to me as I just needed it for a handful of templates so I just manually edited them.

Cheers,
Ben